# How to replace line breaks (\n) with <br> for textual data to html content

Tags: python, django

I am loading data from a database. The textual data has line breaks `\n` as uploaded by the user, I would like to print this data on a html page. However line breaks do not occur. I have tried replacing `\n` with `<br>`, but that prints with `<br>` as part of the string instead of actually breaking the line.

How I replace

```
value['description'].replace('\n', '<br>')
```

How it appears:

[image: screenshot showing literal <br>s in text]

Comment: Your markup gets escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized mine is a framework specific issue as guided by @Demian Wolf's comment, my html markup was getting escaped. Since I am using django framework, adding a `safe` call in was the solution.

```
{{ value.description | safe }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) templatetag

```
{{ value|linebreaksbr }}
```

or in your view

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaksbr
linebreaksbr(value['description'])
```